# C# OOP Limitations for Interfaces is killing my project

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface

Is there any way to simulate Multiple Inheritance in C#? I know there isn't so I need help finding a way around.

So I have a project, and it has classes, and one type of these classes is responsible for providing a comparison functionality to a manager. So naturally the functionality is an Interface.

```
interface StringCompareString
{
    string getName();

    ErrorState compare_two_strings(string[] inputs, ref double[] similarities);
    ErrorState compare_two_strings(string input1, string input2, ref double similarity);
}
```

now here is the deal, there are two variations to the comparison function, one of them gets a bunch of strings, and is supposed to to compare them all somehow to each other, and the other receives just two strings, and is supposed to compare just these two. However I want the implementors (people in my group who don't do management code) to receive a default compare_two_strings of the first viriaty.

namely this function

Note: the only thing that is important in the functions itself is that this function must reference the simple version of compare_two_strings.

```
ErrorState compare_two_strings(string[] inputs, ref double[] similarities)
{
    similarities = new double[inputs.Count() * (inputs.Count() - 1) / 2];

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Count(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < inputs.Count(); ++j)
        {
            double finality = -1;
            compare_two_strings(inputs[i], inputs[j], ref finality);
            similarities[count] = finality;
            ++count;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I want to define this function at Interface level. And then other classes who : Inherit this Interface to have this function definition as a default implementation. And these classes already used up their one time ticket of Inheriting. And c# doesn't allow for any function definition in the Interface, or Multiple Inheritance. What to do, what to do?

The ugly approach would be to copy paste that function implementation into every single one of those classes, which is very bad design.

Ok thank you all for propositions, I learned a lot of new buzz words at the very very least. In the end the decision was to use composition but not on the Interface. I'll use composition on the classes that StringCompareString already inherits from, which would free up the Inheritance for an abstract class instead of the Interface.

Comment: "C# OOP Limitations for Interfaces is killing my project" --- you would never say that. It's your app design kills itself.

Comment: If you're already inheriting from something, why doesn't that "something" implement the interface in its portion that interest you?

Comment: Some side notes, rather than returning an error state, you're probably better off just using Exceptions.  Throw one when you have an error you can't handle, have the callers catch them when they can handle them.  You should also generally avoid `ref` parameters.  Either return those values as results (now that you don't need to return error codes), or use `out` if the input values aren't read by the method.

Comment: Multiple inheritance is a smell for a design problem

Comment: I'm asking for help to a better design, btw its a 20,000+ size project with over 50 different classes as of now. So any design decisions are critical, but the most fundamentally critical decision was the choice of language, which I'm regretting, but there nothing to do now.

Comment: Well, you are getting help for better design. As many have pointed out, you can use composition instead of inheritance for this default implementation.

Comment: about the ErrorStates, its one of the design decisions that have nothing to do with my current problem, but as a side note, exceptions are not good because they throw you out of blocks of code, and in this project I want to continue no matter what. There are still exceptions though if you wonder.

Comment: Composition solves nothing for me, (at least not in my mind), if you could specifically say who will compose of what, we can discuss that

Comment: 20,000+ lines and 50 classes is nothing... Code can always be refactored (and should be). Don't blame the language just because you don't know how to use it.

Comment: @G.Stoynev because that something belongs to a different group of people whose Interface serves a very different purpose. Mixing purposes is a way around, though it would make things even uglier then copy pasting the code around in the inheriters.

Comment: Do you understand what we mean by composition ? Instead of having a "is-a" relationship, you have "uses-a" one. As another poster explains, you pass an object that implements the default two string compare functions when you instantiate your objects, delegating the method calls of your interface to this object's methods.

Comment: @DaveZych they say that the customer is always right, I dont blame no language, I blame other peoples choices in the past which I had no control over.

Comment: @mrlucmorin do you understand the implications of your design? it would mean that every guy who creates a class for this functionality needs to have the same constructor implementation, but for this class already inherits. So what you suggest is basically every class implementation having the same constructor? well thats a bunch of copy pasting, and is what I claimed is the ugly solution.

Comment: Ok, you're the boss... we're just trying to help you you know. Nobody is forcing you to accept any of our answers.

Comment: As a side note, composition doesn't have to be done through the constructor. You could use setter injection (also known as property injection).

Comment: I looked into this composition thing, I worry though that it would complicate things way beyond the naive solution. I still after thinking about all those generous Answers how Composition would save code copying. As the meaning of it is that I need new object which means a new class, for every single class that Inherits from stringComparestring. nvm, I'll go sleep, maybe I'll figure something out and let you guys know, thank you for the gathered forces.

Comment: Have you looked into extension methods?

Comment: @miniBill wow those extension methods, thats crazy :). And I though I saw everything.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to have implementors that are only actually intending to implement one of the two methods then you shouldn't have them together in the same interface.

Create two interfaces, one for each method; this way if someone wants to provide an implementation of just one of the two methods they can do so.

Provide two types, one for each interface, that has a "Default" implementation of that interface.  It might make sense for this type to be a Singleton.  It wouldn't *need* to be, but it's worth considering.

A consumer can use just one of the interfaces if it only needs one of the methods; it it needs both methods then it can simply accept two objects.  It could happen to be a single instance that implements both interfaces, it could be a copy of the default type and one of a custom type, two different custom types, or whatever.

If it's important to pass around some single instance of *something* that can do all of these things (either by necessity, for interoping with some library, or just for convenience, if consumers will always need all of these things) then create interfaces just for the individual methods, leave this composite interface, and then create a class that implements the "big" interface will all of the methods, takes objects representing each of the "smaller" interfaces, and then just dispatches all of the relevant method calls to the composed object.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you, in fact I'm sure I didn't but two interfaces does seem likely

Comment: @user3167049 What don't you understand, in particular?

Answer (score 1):

What you'd usually do in this case is to use *dependency injection*.

Say, you have a class `StringCompareString` that provides *only* the string comparison functionality:

```
public sealed class StringCompareString
{
    public ErrorState Compare(string[] inputs, ref double[] similarities)
    {
        // Implementation here...
    }

    public ErrorState Compare(string input1, string input2, ref double similarity)
    {
        // Implementation here...
    }
}
```

And you have a class `MyClass` that wants to compare strings. Then you provide the `StringCompareString` to the class through its constructor. For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private StringCompareString comparer;

    public MyClass(StringCompareString comparer)
    {
        if (comparer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        this.comparer = comparer;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Some code that uses the comparer:
        this.comparer.Compare("String 1", "String 2", ...);
    }
}
```

Your `MyClass` now has a *dependency* on `StringCompareString`, and you've *injected* it through its constructor. You can easily swap the `StringCompareString` implementation with a different implementation. And any class only has to take a `StringCompareString` as a constructor argument to use it. No more code copying.

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of having everything inherit from this interface, you make the classes that require this functionality accept this functionality as a constructor parameter?

Example

```
public class Foo : FooBase
{
    //access StringCompareString functionality through this member instead
    //of some base class
    private readonly StringCompareString _comparer;

    public Foo(StringCompareString comparer)
    {
        _comparer = comparer;
    }

}
```